# How do I dynamically control animations in PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I'm playing around with PowerPoint creating a trivia game. When the user clicks on a tile on the main slide it advances to another slide with the question. When the user clicks the return button, they should return to the main slide (simple enough), but the tile that they had previously clicked on should disappear so that they cannot click on it again. It's a simple matter to make the tile disappear, but when returning to the title slide, all tiles reappear. I cannot figure out how to save the state of the animation so that they are not on the screen any more. I'm guessing this will need to be done with VBA, but my VBA knowledge is a bit limited. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A friend of mine, David Marcovitz, has written a book about this kind of thing and includes a LOT of useful examples on his web site: loyola.edu/edudept/PowerfulPowerPoint/index.html

Answer (score 0):

An ugly, brute force solution that may lead to a maintenance nightmare
is to have an obscene number of copies of the page. 
(And I guess that probably means an obscene number of copies of *each* page.) 
For example

```
X a     X a     X a     X a     X a     X a     X a     X a
X b     X b     X b     X b     X       X       X       X
X c     X c     X       X       X c     X c     X       X
X d     X       X d     X       X d     X       X d     X
```

would be the first 8 of the 16 (2<sup>4</sup>) copies that you would need
if you have four tiles.

Using VBA would probably be a more scalable approach.

Comment: Right, I considered the page approach, but that's too intensive. VBA would be fine, but my VBA experience is too limited to know what to do. I'd still need advice there.

Comment: My VBA experience/knowledge is also severely limited; I might be able to grind out something that would help you, but there are probably people here who could do it in their sleep.  I suggest that you edit your question.  (1) Put in a bit more detail, like maybe mock-ups of what you want your slide to look like, before and after.  Consider changing the title; e.g., "How do I dynamically hide elements on a PowerPoint slide?"  And (2) tag it [vba] (and maybe mention VBA in the text of the question).  That might attract some more attention.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: Thanks for contributing, but your comment might be more effective if you attached it to the question, rather than my answer.  Consider: since the OP has, essentially, rejected my answer, I might just delete it.  (I probably won't, but I *could*.)  Also, if other people who have similar problems find this question, they aren't likely to read all the comments *on my answer*.

Comment: @scott  Thanks, you're right. I've added it as a comment to the original.  Delete away, if you wish.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: I was going to explain that I don't have the power to delete *your* comments,, but you do — but it looks like you already figured that out.